# Windows tool to analyze PostgreSQL log files

Tags: postgresql, logging, analysis

I've activated log_duration in my PostgreSQL configuration in order to find out what the most expensive queries are.

Now I am looking for a tool (Windows) that enables me to analyze the resulting log files. Can you recommend anything?

bye & thanks a lot
    Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one I know about is pgFouine:

http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/

It's implemented in PHP, so it should run on Windows as well.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. As it is an PHP app, it works fine on Linux and Windows.